# Parse iOS background notifications without clicking on them

Tags: swift, background, apple-push-notifications

When my app is in the background state and I receive a notification; I want to parse the payload of the notification without clicking on the notification.

Is it possible to get notified when a background notification arrives?

Answer (score 0):

If you've truly sent a background notification via the `content-available` payload key being set to a value of `1`, then your app delegate will call `application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler)`